# How does nservicebus saga holds the data when using timeouts and when firing up after the timeout how does it maintains the correlation

Tags: timeout, nservicebus, saga

I have got saga and due to some requirement we need to process the messages further down with a delay.

I am thinking of using the timeout.
I was wondering how would saga come to know which message next to process and how do it correlates..

Answer (score 0):

The timeouts carry with them the saga id along with a correlation id.  Timeouts also allow for you to pass along some state information.  You could leverage that state to make decisions or have that state maintained in the saga itself.